# Can anyone suggest data science project

Tags: web-scraping, data-science, data-analysis, data-scrubbing, graph-data-science

I just completed data science topic i want to fo a mini project in data science can anyone suggest me a project . I searched a lot in google but i not found any projects can anyonr suggest a project

Comment: Create a profile in kaggle.com, and join any beginner level competition and play around with the dataset. Most famous ones are house prediction (for regression) and titanic (for classification).

Comment: Agreeing with @SupratimHaldar the Titanic problem is a prediction on whether a certain person would survive the Titanic based on features about them. It's a good exercise in data cleaning, feature engineering and is a classification problem that can be solved with a lot of different methods. It's a toy problem, but a good one.

Answer (score 4):

The beauty of data science is that the project can be anything you're curious about. To figure out what kind of project you want to tackle, **what kind of questions do you want to know the answers to?**

At the top of my head, you could explore:

- the various COVID related data try to find any insights or simply
- the price differences of peaches around different areas of Atlanta,
  GA
- is there a particular skill you want to improve such as time series analysis, classification, or regression?

Find a question you want to answer or a project that will improve your skill in a certain area.

Answer (score 2):

Try this project :

https://www.udemy.com/course/data-science-hands-on-1-hour-project-on-deep-learning/

The Hands on project is currently free on Udemy. It uses Image localization techniques to build, train and test deep learning model for autonomous vehicles. Try changing the data set and try something more innovative liks skin cancer detection or text detection. Try it once.

Answer (score -1):

Try creating a project on no of accidents happened in your country or state, due to different conditions like natural calamities or human mistakes or due to animals and predict the no of cases for the next upcoming year.

Try creating a time series analysis project on covid - 19.